MLE of marginal distribution for continuous random variable
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of multivariate probability densities such that for a sufficiently large data sample, there always exists a unique MLE. Assume also that all marginal and conditional densities of any $f \in \mathcal{F}$ belong to the same family (on fewer variables). Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an i.i.d. data sample from some continuous random vector. For simplicity, assume I want to estimate the marginal density on the first variable. Is it legit to claim that
$\arg \max_{f_1\in \mathcal{F_1}}\sum_{i=1}^n\log f_1(x_{1,i})$
corresponds to the MLE of the marginal density on the first coordinate? Here, $\mathcal{F_1}$ refers to the univariate version of $\mathcal{F}$ and $x_{1,i}$ is the projection of $x_i$ on the first coordinate.
In my opinion, this should be correct because almost surely $x_{1,i}\neq x_{1,j}$ for any distinct $i$ and $j$, so there is a bijection between the sample points and its projection and I expect that the projection is still i.i.d. Hence, the empirical distribution does not get distorted during the projection, and the projection of the original data sample can be viewed as if it was directly sampled from the marginal.
Does this reasoning make sense? I think I can prove this by writing out how marginal of the empirical density on the original sample looks like, but I am worried that I am misunderstanding something fundamental about sampling and marginalisation.

Your notation seems inconsistent, because $f$ denotes a "multivariate probability density" but in your formula "$f(x_{1,n})$" it appears you are applying it to a scalar.  (There must be a typo there anyway, because "$i$" doesn't appear.)  Consequently I haven't been able to figure out what you are asking.  Could you clarify?

@whuber Fixed the typos. Thank you! Basically, imagine that X=(X_1,..,X_d) is a multivariate Gaussian and you want to estimate the marginal of X_1. Can you just project the sample on the first coordinate and estimate X_1?

Yes: that is tantamount to ignoring all the information in the remaining $d-1$ variables.

This is precisely the source of my confusion: marginals do not ignore other variables but integrate them out. My approach wouldn't work for discrete variables because multiple points could have the same projection. But for continuous, this shouldn't be the case, so my hope is that projecting approximates integration

By definition marginals have nothing to do with the other variables.  Otherwise, what do you suppose "integrate out" means?
